# Connect and disconnect a MutationObserver with button click

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to work out if I could connect / reconnect and disconnect an MutationObserver with a button. Can this even be done?

```
(function() {
  var respawnBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("hud-respawn-btn")[0];
  var hudRespawn = document.getElementsByClassName("hud-respawn")[0];

  RESPAWN = function() {
    respawnBtn.attributes.class.value = 'hud-respawn-btn';
    respawnBtn.click();
  };

  var obs = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutationRecord) {
      RESPAWN();
    });
  });

  obs.observe(hudRespawn, {
    attributes: true,
    attributeFilter: ['style']
  });
})();
```

This is what I was thinking and tried but I can't seem to work it out.

```
<button class="btn btn-green" style="width: 50%;" onclick="checkobs();">ON & OFF</button> 

function checkobs() {
 if (????????) {
  obs.disconnect();
  } else {
    obs.observe(hudRespawn, {
      attributes: true,
      attributeFilter: ['style']
    });
  }
}
```

I would really appreciate any info / help.

Comment: one of the options: Initialize the state isObserve
var isObserve = true
if(isObserve) {
  isObserve = !isObserve;
}

Comment: You should consider using `respawnBtn.classList.toggle('hud-respawn-btn')`.